# Is it possible to create "cron" jobs with Python?

Tags: python, cron

I would like to give the user the possibility to have a function being executed every 30 minutes and also be able to stop this whenever he wants. (The user interacts with my application with a web frontend.)

How would one do so with Python?

### What I thought of

One possibility I thought of is subprocess + infinite loop with `time.sleep`:

1. The Python function gets it's own script `whatever.py` which has a command line parameter `stop_filename`
2. As soon as the user wants to start this "cron" job, `subprocess` creates a new process of `whatever.py` with a `stop_filename = "kill_job/{}".format(uuid.uuid4())`
3. When the user wants to stop the process, the file `stop_filename` is created. The process always checks if this file exists before the function is executed and termines if the file does exist.
4. I store the generated `stop_filename` in the database for each process so that the user only needs to know which "cron job" he wants to kill.

Although this will work, there are a couple of things I don't like about it:

- The process killing might take 30 minutes
- The process could be dead before and I don't know how to check that
- It seems to be too complicated.

Comment: I don't know if [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) is something that can help you

Comment: I would uses schedule as @MartinAlonso said. Maybe you will need [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) too to handle several users's "crons"

Comment: @MartinAlonso My webserver would start the job. If I use schedule, do I have any possibility to kill the job (without killing the webserver)?

Comment: Read schedule [Frequently Asked Questions](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html)

Comment: How is `schedule` better than `crontab`?